# How to load FRL into Clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I downloaded clisp from https://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/ and cloned FRL from github repo https://github.com/lispm/FRL/tree/master

I tried following the following instructions https://github.com/lispm/FRL/blob/master/setup.text but on step 3 I got next error:

```
Break 5 [8]> (load "labs/FRL/init.lisp")
;;     Loading file labs\FRL\init.lisp ...
*** - READ: input stream #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"labs\\FRL\\init.lisp" @72> ends within a token
      after multiple escape character
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R2      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R3      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R4      Abort debug loop
SKIP           :R5      skip (PACKAGE-DECLARE FRL GLOBAL ...)
RETRY          :R6      retry (PACKAGE-DECLARE FRL GLOBAL ...)
STOP           :R7      stop loading file D:\University\Subjects\knowledge engineering\CLISP\clisp-2.49\labs\FRL\frlpkg.lisp
ABORT          :R8      Abort debug loop
SKIP           :R9      skip (PACKAGE-DECLARE FRL GLOBAL ...)
RETRY          :R10     retry (PACKAGE-DECLARE FRL GLOBAL ...)
STOP           :R11     stop loading file D:\University\Subjects\knowledge engineering\CLISP\clisp-2.49\labs\FRL\frlpkg.lisp
ABORT          :R12     Abort main loop
```

Comment: From the readme.text file (emphasis added): The code in this repository might run in Franz Lisp and Lisp Machine Lisp.
*It probably does not run in Common Lisp.*

Comment: I'm surprised that you successfully performed step 1, "Set the LISP and COMPLR variables in the makefile to be the system franz lisp and franz liszt programs."

Comment: [PC-LISP](https://github.com/blakemcbride/PC-LISP) claims to be a Franz Lisp implementation. Might check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, you can't: FRL was written for [MACLISP](https://www.maclisp.info/) and [Franz Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Lisp), both of which are obsolete Lisp dialects which predated CL.  The instructions in `setup.text` are describing how to get it to work on Franz Lisp (so probably on a Vax).  This is historical code.

You might be able to make a lot of changes to it to make it work, but it's not going to work out of the box.  You also might be able to coerce some version of either MACLISP or Franz Lisp to run: MACLISP would need a PDP-10 emulator, there was a port of Franz Lisp to x86 but it was 30 years ago now: I have no idea if it would still work / be possible to make it work.

Comment: [PC-LISP](https://github.com/blakemcbride/PC-LISP) is probably OP's best bet for Franz Lisp on modern computers.